# How to add suffix text into EditText after write on Keyboard on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In my application I want use `EditText` and I want after user write on keyboard add **suffix** text into `EditText`.
I write below codes, but when user write on keyboard application has freeze!

```
loginPage4SelectTxt.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

                }

                override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                    loginPage4SelectTxt.setText("$p0 Kg")
                }
            })
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the contents of `loginPage4SelectTxt` changes, those `*Changed` callbacks fire in order. What are you doing in the last one?

You're changing the contents, which makes the whole thing start over, which makes the whole things start over, forever and ever. [You have to be careful about making changes to an `EditText` inside its own `TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)), or you can end up in an infinite loop

> It is legitimate to make further changes to `s` from this callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, **because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively**.

So you need a way to ignore the changes you're causing with your "update", and only respond to events triggered by actual text entry. You can do that with an `updating` flag (or whatever you want to call it):

```
loginPage4SelectTxt.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    // use this to track whether an update is in progress,
    // so we can avoid retriggering it
    var updating = false

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) { }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) { }

    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        // skip if an update is happening - this avoids the infinite loop
        if (!updating) {
            // we're doing an update - set the flag so we don't end up
            // back in here
            updating = true
            // this will trigger the TextWatcher callbacks -immediately-, this code
            // won't continue until those are finished
            loginPage4SelectTxt.setText("$p0 Kg")
            // text is changed and the resulting callbacks have finished - we're done
            // updating, so set it to false so the next change will be handled properly
            updating = false
        }
    }
})
```